# jQuery , bind a callback to any function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to bind a callback function to a previously defined function
and being able to use two variables defined in the scope of that function.

It should look like this:

```
function mainFunction(){
  var localForMain;
}

 $(document).ready(function(){

     // bind a call back method to the 'mainFunction'
     $(mainFunction).bindCallback(function(){

        // ...use the localForMain variable HERE;

     });


 });
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: How should this callback for a function work? Should it be called when the `mainFunction` is called? This is not possible.

Comment: yes  , it should fire right after the mainFunction execution

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible to bind call back function in such way. You have to program it inside the function.

```
function SampleWithCallBack(callbackfunction)
{
      code here
      callbackfunction(params);
}
```

about the use of defined variable in the context. You should pass the variables in parameters or define it globally which is not a very good way

Comment: Actually that is the solution that I'm trying to avoid.
My idea/question is , to do that in a way to extend that function whiteout writing directly to it.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you need to be in scope of `mainFunction`. It could be done fairly easy:

```
function mainFunction(){
  var localForMain;


 $(document).ready(function(){

     // bind a call back method to the 'mainFunction'
     $(mainFunction).bindCallback(function(){

        // NOW YOU CAN USE the localForMain variable HERE;

     });


 });
```

}

Comment: `jQuery#bindCallback` does not exist so this code example wouldn’t work.

Comment: here is the deal , I have multiple files where I'm 'overwriting' the same method (defining it over and over again for different pages , with slightly different functionality ) , so I would like to write an other method in order to 'extend' the functionality.

Comment: @Antagonist: Maybe you have to rethink your design. You could e.g. create an object instead which has a 'main' function which calls sub functions defined by your other code.

Comment: I just changed my design ,
Inside the mainFunction I have set two function , setBefore() and setAfter() , (you can guess where I have placed them exactly) , 
that way I will be extending my mainFunction when ever I want from only one place , 
tnx anyway.