# javascript bind callback to any function

Tags: javascript, callback, bind

I would like to bind or chain a callback/function to another function.

There is a similar question (without any valid answer): [jQuery , bind a callback to any function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661264/jquery-bind-a-callback-to-any-function)

But, for me I would not want to be limited only to jQuery realm.
I looking for a broader answer, I wonder if it's possible with vanilla javascript or library other than jQuery.

Example:

```
// a function which I don't want or I can't edit it's body
var thirdPartyObject = {
    doSomething: function(args) {
        // a lot of code
        console.log('doing stuff: ' + args);
    }
};

// my function
var easyCallback = function() {
    // processing stuff
    console.log('doing more stuff');
}

// the bind 
magicLibrary.bind(thirdPartyObject.doSomething, easyCallback);

// run
thirdPartyObject.doSomething(1);
thirdPartyObject.doSomething(10);
```

When I run this "code", the following output represents the behaviour I'm looking for:

```
doing stuff: 1
doing more stuff
doing stuff: 10
doing more stuff
```

**Is it possible?**

---

**EDIT**: the `bind` is a conceptual term, maybe you think this like a `chain`, `trigger` or even another term.

But the import is the second function or callback which in my example is `easyCallback()` must be somehow connected to the first one `doSomething()`.

And every time the `doSomething()` is called or executed I want the `easyCallback()` to be executed as well after the first is finished.

But the without "wrapping" them around or without rewriting the first one.

Comment: Just define a function that calls one and then the other `var callsBoth = function() { myEasyCallback(thirdParty.something()); });`

Comment: that is not bind or chain, that is wrapping the function, but I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You would have to wrap the `doSomething` function inside yet another function, like so:

```
// a function which I don't want or I can't edit it's body
var thirdPartyObject = {
    doSomething: function(args) {
        // a lot of code
        console.log('doing stuff: ' + args);
    }
};

// my function
var easyCallback = function() {
    // processing stuff
    console.log('doing more stuff');
}

// the bind 
// magicLibrary.bind(thirdPartyObject.doSomething, easyCallback);
const doSomething = thirdPartyObject.doSomething.bind(thirdPartyObject);
thirdPartyObject.doSomething = function(args) {
    doSomething(args);
    easyCallback(args);
};

// run
thirdPartyObject.doSomething(1);
thirdPartyObject.doSomething(10);
```

Comment: @Jasmshid Asadzadeh thanks for your answer. Altought it works for this generic example, but is not exactly how I pictured. Because this `binds` the original version of the function to the object `thirdPartyObject`, then creates a "snapshot" of it on a new reference and finally rewrites the `doSomething` function where we wrap the functions.

Comment: @PauloOliveira please, describe what you want, exactly

Comment: @Jasmshid Asadzadeh my apologizes, I edit the post, I tried to explain the best I can, please warn me if still missing information or if it became more confusing.
I apppreciate the time you are taking. :)

Comment: @PauloOliveira I don't think you do that any other way than wrapping the `doSomething` function

Comment: @Jasmshid Asadzadeh thank you very much, I already had said it, though your answer works (even upvoted it), but is not exactly what I'm looking for, so I will let this question unsolved.